# How to fix SD Card partition resize mistake?

Tags: sd-card, retropie, storage, raspberry-pi-os

Im new to RaspberryPi and also Linux so bare with my ignorance. My RetroPi SD card stopped uploading due to which turned out to be a common problem of the SD drive being full... even though it wasnt even close to be full!

I found a good option on Stack Exch ([Resize file system on OpenELEC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/resize-file-system-on-openelec) to resize the SD partitions, it was all going to plan until it wasnt.

Now I've managed to delete all the partitions on the SD drive and Retropi wont upload without the apparently. Does anyone know if I can reinstall the partitions on an SD Reader? It seems possible but I'd rather not do more damage if avoidable...

Any help would be greatly appriciated!
Thanks
[image]

Comment: We will bear with "ignorance" (and spelling) but if you deleted all partitions everything is gone. If you know the original partition locations it is possible to recover, but your best bet is to restore from your backup.

Comment: Once you have recovered from backup (or rebuilt) I would see if a program called gparted can be installed on Retropi - it is a GUI and lets you plan changes before implemented (and has an undo before commit capability).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a back-up SD card, I would simply try again from scratch. It sounds as though you're trying to preserve the current partitioning of it whilst attempting a reformat. It doesn't work like that. You have to start from the beginning with a fresh card.